How to get inputs from a mobile virtual keyboard in MAUI?
I would like to be able to know which key is pressed on a mobile keypad, but @onkeyup only triggers when the mobile equivalent of enter is pressed, with KeyboardEventArgs.Code equaling an empty string. I have tried looking up any information on a mobile equivalent of KeyboardEventArgs, or even just why @onkeyup doesn't trigger when every key is pressed despite onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" working on each key stroke just fine. I'm frankly bamboozled.
HTML code that works:
<input @bind="StringInput" id="textInput" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" />

Blazor code I've tried:
<input @bind="StringInput" id="textInput" @onkeyup="InputReceivedInput" />

@code {
    private string StringInput = string.Empty;

    private void InputReceivedInput(KeyboardEventArgs Args)
    {
        if (Args.Code == "Enter" || Args.Code == "NumpadEnter")
        {
            //call another function
        }
        else
        {
            StringInput = StringInput.ToUpper();
        }
    }
}

Second Attempt (only changed HTML portion):
<input @bind="StringInput" id="textInput" onkeyup="@InputReceivedInput" />


I think that is rather impossible, according to Android documentation: "As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular, the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later...". See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent

That sucks. Is there an ontextchange function I could use instead? Maybe I can check it for '\n' each time...

You can use TextChange event: "In addition, InputView defines a TextChanged event, which is raised when the text in the Entry changes. The TextChangedEventArgs object that accompanies the TextChanged event has NewTextValue and OldTextValue properties, which specify the new and old text, respectively.". See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry?view=net-maui-8.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.entry.completed?view=net-maui-8.0

I tested the code you provided, and the onkeyup method has the issue that it cannot update the data after pressing a button on the keyboard. For this issue, you can report it on the GitHub issue.
In addition, I found another way to achieve this: using the @bind:get and  @bind:set. For more information, you can check this document about ASP.NET Core Blazor data binding.
<input @bind:event="oninput" @bind:get="StringInput" @bind:set="OnInput" id="textInput" />

<p>
    <code>StringInput</code>: @StringInput
</p>

<input @bind="StringInput" id="textInput" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" />

@code {
    private string StringInput = string.Empty;

    private void OnInput(string value)
    {
        var newValue = value ?? string.Empty;

        StringInput = newValue.ToUpper();
    }
}


Unfortunately, while this code still does not allow me to detect when the enter key has been pressed, the alternative you found with @bind:get and @bind:set allows the text to appear on the screen in uppercase form, rather than first showing as lowercase and then updating. Thanks!
